# couldn't fetch mysqli in opencart 3

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I got this error when I move my opencart files to live server. Its worked in local server without any issue.

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): No such file or
>   directory in
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web39/web/system/library/db/mysqli.php on
>   line 7Warning: DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web39/web/system/library/db/mysqli.php on
>   line 10Warning: DB\MySQLi::__construct(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web39/web/system/library/db/mysqli.php on
>   line 10

How can I solve the issue?